# Proper command to input YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' in SAS

Tags: sas

I have data in csv format with a certain timestamp field in this format:

' 2009-07-30 20:50:19'

How can I read that into a SS dataset? Ive been trying this, but to no avail.

```
             data filecontents;
             infile       "C:\es.txt" dlm=',' MISSOVER DSD firstobs=2 lrecl=32767 ;
             input  START_TIME :ANYDTDTM. 
             FORMAT START_TIME datetime.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems fine to me.  The below code works on my machine (9.3 TSM2).  What happens for you?  Are you just missing a semicolon after the input statement (your example code is)?

```
data test;
infile "c:\temp\test.csv" dlm=',' missover;
input 
    dtvar :YMDDTTM.
    var1 $
    var2 $;
format dtvar DATETIME19.;
put dtvar= DATETIME19.;
run;
```

result:

```
608  data test;
609  infile "c:\temp\test.csv" dlm=',' missover;
610  input
611      dtvar :YMDDTTM.
612      var1 $
613      var2 $;
614  format dtvar DATETIME19.;
615  put dtvar= DATETIME19.;
616  run;

NOTE: The infile "c:\temp\test.csv" is:
      Filename=c:\temp\test.csv,
      RECFM=V,LRECL=256,File Size (bytes)=31,
      Last Modified=20Nov2012:20:20:51,
      Create Time=20Nov2012:20:17:51

dtvar=30JUL2009:20:50:19
NOTE: 1 record was read from the infile "c:\temp\test.csv".
      The minimum record length was 29.
      The maximum record length was 29.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TEST has 1 observations and 3 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

For what it's worth, YMDDTTMw.d is the specific informat for that (ANYDTDTM. will work as well of course).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that statement, other than the missing semicolon again; you might check that you're not missing that semicolon in the actual code.  The number you're seeing is the underlying representation of the value.  Where are you seeing it - by viewing the datatable in SAS, or in some form of export?

Comment: In my example code I didn't include the format statement (since it's a _null_ step, and it wasn't clear that was your problem).  I edited it to include the format statement, which for me at least works fine.